# How to import nwjs in ES6/typescript?

Tags: ecmascript-6, nwjs, angular1.6

In ES6, I want to use this sample code in angular 1.6 code.

```
var win = nw.Window.get();

win.on('new-win-policy', function(frame, url, policy){
    policy.forceNewWindow();
});
```

These are the steps I did,(updated package.json)

```
npm install nwjs
```

in code,

```
import nw from 'nwjs'; //I guess this is not correct
```

please help what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Are there any errors? Also note that node doesn't support `import` by default so you need to either transpile it, replace it with `require` or run node with `--experimental-modules`

Comment: Error on fetch for nwjs.js at file:///Users/[Project_Dir]/nwjs.js, I am using gulp task to transpile.

Answer (score 0):

did you try ?

```
import nw = require('nwjs');
```

not sure if this works in angular project but this is how i use it in Node + Typescript.

Comment: you meant let nw = require('nwjs');?

Comment: nop - the way i wrote it above is how i use it in my current project (node + typescript)

Comment: @user17 that's because its typescript. It's the equivalent of `import * as nw from 'nwjs';`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import {} from 'nw.js';
```